# python list - only keep only-positive or only-negative values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python, I have a list with thousands of numbers (negative and positive).

What I want, is to eliminate the numbers which occur in the list both positive and negative. So I want only to keep the numbers which occur in the list either only positive or only negative.

Example: `list = (1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -5, 6, 7, -6)` should result in `(3, -5, 7)`.

Thanks !

Comment: Side note, don't name variables after built-ins, e.g. use `L` instead of `list`.

Comment: How should duplicates by handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
l = [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -5, 6, 7, -6]
print([i for i in set(l) if -i not in l])
```

**Output:**

```
[3, -5, 7]
```

Comment: Also, good practice not to name variables `l`. This can be confused with `I` with many fonts.

Comment: But be aware that because of `set(l)` the new list has no more duplicates even if all of them were either positive or negative!

Answer (score 3):

You can use hashing via `set` to ensure O(n) complexity in the average case.

```
from operator import neg

A = [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -5, 6, 7, -6]
A_set = set(A)
exc = A_set & set(map(neg, A_set))
res = [i for i in A if i not in exc]

# [3, -5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just sets:

```
from operator import neg

data = (1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -5, 6, 7, -6)
set_data = set(data)
set_neg = set(map(neg, set_data))

print(set_data & (set_data ^ set_neg))
```

Giving:

```
{-5, 3, 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a new list to store that.

Try this..

```
for i in list:
   op = i * -1
   if op not in list:
      newlist.add(i)
```